# AstronomicalData and Planetary Heliocentric (x,y,z) Velocity Components

Tags: curated-data, astronomy

I'm trying to find data on the heliocentric velocities of planets in our solar system and was directed to *Mathematica*'s `AstronomicalData` in a previous topic. Unfortunately I cannot find any x,y and z velocity components and was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

An approximation (speed is in m/s and Position in m):

```
AstronomicalData["Mars", {"Speed", {2019, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0}}] Normalize @@
   Differences[ AstronomicalData[ "Mars", {"Position", {2019, 3, 1, 0, 0, #}}] & /@ {0, 1}]

(*
  {-22373.4, 8780.75, 734.403}
*)
```

Comment: +1 Consider a central difference instead: it should be more accurate.  It makes a substantial difference, by the way: it affects the third sig. fig. in your example, because it reflects the net planetary acceleration during the course of 12 hours.

Comment: @whuber Perhaps I'm wrong, but I think I'm taking _one second_ differences, not _one day_. Even within 10 seconds, there aren't appreciable speed changes (as expected, of course)

Comment: Central difference: `{1, -1}.(AstronomicalData["Mars", {"Position", DatePlus[{2019, 3, 3}, {#, "Second"}]}] & /@ {1, -1}/2)`. Normalize and multiply with the speed afterwards. :)

Comment: Would something like this not work as well?

    v = ((AstronomicalData[
    "Mars", {"Position", {2013, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.01}}] - 
    AstronomicalData["Mars", {"Position", {2013, 1, 1, 1, 1,1}}]))/0.01

Comment: @J.M. `Normalize[{1, -1}.(AstronomicalData[
        "Mars", {"Position", 
         DatePlus[{2019, 3, 1}, {#, "Second"}]}] & /@ {1, -1}/
     2)] AstronomicalData["Mars", {"Speed", {2019, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0}}]` gives the same result as mine. That's why I don't understand whuber's comment. I'm forgetting something, surely

Comment: @bel, I suppose that in this particular case there's not much of a difference; nevertheless; it is true that almost always, the central difference gives more accurate approximations than the forward or backward differences; since all of those require two function evaluations anyway, one might want to prefer the central difference.

Comment: @J.M. Sure, the approx is one order better. But in this case I can't find the improvements whuber mentions (_"it affects the third sig. fig. in your example"_)

Comment: I can't really say. Let's wait for @whuber to elucidate...

Comment: @user7388 It's a matter of choosing approximations. Compare `AstronomicalData["Mars", {"Speed", 
  DatePlus[{2019, 3, 1}, {1, "Second"}]}]`with `Norm[{1, -1}.((AstronomicalData[
        "Mars", {"Position", 
         DatePlus[{2019, 3, 1}, {#, "Second"}]}]/.01) & /@ {1, 1.01})]`

Comment: Oh okay I see, so would a simple (delta x)/(delta t) be regarded as inaccurate?

Now that I have a way of finding out initial positions and velocities, all I need is to have time "pass by" a lot faster so I don't have to wait 365 days to see my simulated Earth complete a single orbit. Is there a way to increase the time steps or each calculation?

Comment: @user7388 You may want to interpolate. I suggest posting another question

Comment: Okay great, I'll start another topic.